Select a combination of distinct column in Snowflake/SQL
I have a table like this:



Col1
Col2
Col3
col4




1
a
e
x


2
b
e
x


3
c
f
y


4
d
f
y



col3 and col4 have duplicates. So I need to select col1, col2 and distinct col3, col4 from the table. All 4 columns may not necessarily need to be distinct but only col3 and col4 need to be.
select col1, col2 distinct col3, col4 
from table 

does not work. What is the best way to achieve this?

Please add the expected result to your question. Since col1 and col2 are always different, I don't understand what you want to do.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Need more information about your use case. select col1, col2 distinct col3, col4 is equivalent to select * and will give you all the rows, explain more what are you trying to do

select  max(col1),max(col2),col3,col4 from so group by col3,col4;

This gives the distinct of col3 and col4 with max of the other 2 columns.

And if they use MIN, they get the min. Since we don't know what they want, better let them explain that before answering.
